# possible to combine sites that have lots of content, into multisite?

Tags: multisite

i run 3 wordpress sites.

they are each on different installations.

i don't really want to combine them right now because i'm not very proficient technically, with wordpress, but i might want to combine them at a later date, to make it easier to administer.

but i want to check in case it's better to set it up now, because i'm just setting one wordpress site up -- maybe it's better to do this now.

so my question is: at a later date, when i have 3 sites running, each with lots of content on, can i combine them at that time?

or does setting up multisite involve starting things from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> at a later date, when i have 3 sites running, each with lots of
>   content on, can i combine them at that time?

Yes, you can. I've found the easiest way to do so is to use the Export/Import feature, but it really depends on the site, and sometimes you have to get creative. Assuming these will be easy, what you would do is setup a multisite install, create new sites within this for each of your 3 solo sites, export XML files from your solo sites, then import those XML files respectively into the new sites in your Multisite network.

Does that make sense?